# PowerShell 5 remoting - JEA with RunAsCredential and Select-Object -Unique

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, powershell-5.0

I am trying to use PowerShell JEA (Just Enough Administration) on a Windows Server 2012 R2 server where I installed WMF 5.

I need to make visible to a non-admin group of users 1 custom function only that relies on another locally installed module. This function does not require admin privileges but needs to run in the context of a particular domain account.

I create a new role capability with my custom function listed in the `VisibleFunctions` section, assign that role to my group of user in the session configuration file (which also contains `RunAsVirtualAccount = $false`) and register this session configuration with the configuration file and the `RunAsCredential` parameter.

When using `Get-PSSessionCapability` locally on the server with an authorized non-admin account, I see my custom function listed.
When I use `Enter-PSSession` from a remote machine (Windows 8.1 with WMF 5 installed) with this constrained endpoint and then use `Get-Command`, the function is not listed.

If I stop using the `RunAsCredential` parameter and instead use `RunAsVirtualACcount = $true` (which would make my function fail but this is for testing only), then I can see my custom function listed with `Get-Command` when executed remotely.
But in that case, trying to call the function results in the following error, which happens even before the missing "RunAs" account authorization error would appear:

```
Select-Object : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Unique'.
```

The `Select-Object` cmdlet is called in the nested 3rd-party module I am using (and thus I cannot replace it with any other function).

Here is the output of `$PSVersionTable` on the server:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.0.10586.117
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.10586.117
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.34014
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Idem on my workstation except for CLRVersion which is `4.0.30319.42000`.

How can I use JEA in my scenario, with a domain account as `RunAsCredential` and calling my 3rd-party module and (among other things) its `Select-Object -Unique` call?

Thank you,

Jordan

Comment: Did you include Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility in your imported modules?

Comment: I just tried and it doesn't help. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue, creating a PS endpoint as a wrapper around the PSPKI module. The PSPKI module uses the Select-Object as well, giving the same error.

solution for me was to update my  endpoint  .psrc file to include an AliasDefinition for Select-Object to point to the FQDN Select-Object.

AliasDefinitions = @{ Name = 'Select-Object' ; Value = 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Select-Object' }

See also: https://jamesone111.wordpress.com/2016/07/01/just-enough-admin-and-constrained-endpoints-part-2-startup-scripts/

Grtx, 
BvZanten

Comment: Hello, thanks for the tip. That seems to fix the select-object issue indeed. But that does not fix the main problem: my custom function is still not visible when using the RunAsCredential configuration. And I can't use virtual accounts unfortunately in my scenario...